# Update method not updating

Tags: c#

I created a player class and I am trying to use my player class to update a player for my menu driven player program. I want to be able to have the user enter a player number and ask if they want to update the player assists and goals then display the updated player information and if the player doesn't exist then it would display the message player does not exist. For some reason when I enter a player number of one of the players I created it still says that the player does not exist even though it was just created. I am not sure on how to fix this.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated please and thanks

```
static void ProcessUpdate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        int player;// Player number to find
        int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
        string answer, answer2;
        //String lastName;
        //int points;

        if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
            player = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
            if (playerindex != -1)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Player {0} currently has {1 goals and {3} assists", players[playerindex].Number,
                        players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists, players[playerindex].Points());
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("\nEdit Goals?: Y/N");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer.Equals('Y'))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's new Goal total");
                    goals = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEdit Assists?: Y/N");
                    answer2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (answer2.Equals('Y'))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's new Assists total");
                        /*assists = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        players[playerindex].LastName = lastName;
                        players[playerindex].FirstName = firstName;
                        players[playerindex].Goals = goals;
                        players[playerindex].Assists = assists;*/
                        Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
                         players[playerindex].Number, players[playerindex].FirstName, players[playerindex].LastName,
                         players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists, players[playerindex].Points());
                        Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Updated!");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }

                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player number does not exists");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
        }
    }
```

> Here is GetPlayerIndex if needed

```
//Returns the index of the player number in the table 
    //or -1 if the number is not found
    static Int32 GetPlayerIndex(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
        Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount)
    {
        Int32 index = 0;
        bool found = false;
        while (index < playerCount && found == false)
             if (players[index].Number == number)
                found = true;
              else
                index++;
        if (found == false)
            index = -1;
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: You are probably not showing us the problem code. Why not use a `List<Player>` instead of `Player[]`?

Comment: You should post the code for `GetPlayerIndex` as well. Something tells me `player` should be passed to it, instead of `number`, but it's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: This is a quite not good piece of code... for sure problem relies somewhere depp in `GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);`

Comment: What is `Int32 number` that's passed in to your ProcessUpdate method (what is its purpose)? It's not very usefully named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
```

To this (just to get it working):

```
playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
```

If you have access to Linq (I sure hope so, unless this is for a class?), I would suggest maintaining a `List<Player>` instead of `Player[]`, and using something similar to following call to find the player by number:

`var player = players.Where(x => x.Number == number).FirstOrDefault();`

After this point, if `player == null`, then you know the player does not exist.